# Serial Port Data Array Extract

Tags: c#, arraylist, serial-port

I know there is load of question regard c# serial port receive and write but i did't found the useful solution in my case. I have write a small program in c# windows application. This application let user to login with mobile miscall. I'm having trouble extracting data which received from serial port. I want to extract mobile number from the output but no luck. Bellow  is my code please tell me how can i extract mobile number from the output and display it in password field. thanks

```
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        port.RtsEnable = true;
        port.DtrEnable = true;
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        if (!port.IsOpen) port.Open();
        port.Write("AT+CLIP=1" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.txtPassword.InvokeRequired)
        {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.txtPassword.Text = text;
        }
    }

    protected void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        string result = currentPort.ReadExisting();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
        //if (!result.Contains("\r\nRING\r\n")) return;
        //currentPort.Write("AT+CHUP" + Environment.NewLine);
        //txtPassword.Text = result.Split('\"')[1];
        //SetText(result.Split('\"')[1]);
        //port.Write("AT+CHUP" + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginUser();
    }
```

The data received from port is below. i want to extract mobile number from it. I'm newbie in C#:

```
RING
+CLIP: "032232323423",161,"",0,"",0
```

When i try to print this code: SetText(result.Split('\"')[1]);
It give me error [Index is out of bound range].

Comment: Use ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting().

Comment: You get the index out of range because there is no `\` character in the string.

Comment: i tried ReadLine() instead of ReadExisting but no luck. Any other idea please?

Answer (score 0):

in the DataReceived event, you can read like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new buffer[1024];
int readBytes = port.Read(buffer, 0, port.BytesToRead);
```

Anyway, I think you can get phone number like this:

```
int firstMark = result.IndexOf('\"');
result.SubString(firstMark, result.IndexOf('\"', firstMark + 1) - firstMark);
```